# python modules missing in sage

Tags: python, module, sage

I have Sage 4.7.1 installed and have run into an odd problem.  Many of my older scripts that use functions like deepcopy() and uniq() no longer recognize them as global names.  I have been able to fix this by importing the python modules one by one, but this is quite tedious.  But when I start the command-line Sage interface, I can type "list2=deepcopy(list1)" without importing the copy module, and this works fine.  How is it possible that the command line Sage can recognize global name 'deepcopy' but if I load my script that uses the same name it doesn't recognize it?

oops, sorry, not familiar with stackoverflow yet. I type: 'sage_4.7.1/sage" to start the command line interface; then, I type "load jbom.py" to load up all the functions I defined in a python script. When I use one of the functions from the script, it runs for a few seconds (complex function) then hits a spot where I use some function that Sage normally has as a global name (deepcopy, uniq, etc) but for some reason the script I loaded does not know what the function is.  And to reiterate, my script jbom.py used to work the last time I was working on this particular research, just as I described.

It also makes no difference if I use 'load jbom.py' or 'import jbom'.  Both methods get the functions I defined in my script (but I have to use jbom. in the second case) and both get the same error about 'deepcopy' not being a global name.

REPLY TO DSM: I have been sloppy about describing the problem, for which I am sorry.  I have created a new script 'experiment.py' that has "import jbom" as its first line.  Executing the function in experiment.py recognizes the functions in jbom.py but deepcopy is not recognized.  I tried loading jbom.py as "load jbom.py" and I can use the functions just like I did months ago.  So, is this all just a problem of layering scripts without proper usage of import/load etc?

SOLVED: I added "from sage.all import *" to the beginning of jbom.py and now I can load experiment.py and execute the functions calling jbom.py functions without any problems.  From the Sage doc on import/load I can't really tell what I was doing wrong exactly.

Comment: How did you install sage? Compiling from source?.. As I recall, it has its own python and everything. You could force running your older scripts with your stock python, to isolate issues.

Comment: What does "load my script" mean?  Sage 4.7.1 should have `deepcopy` available.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, although the oldest Sage I have at hand is 4.7.2.  A 1-line program `print deepcopy` works for me when I `load jbom.py` (because it's a glorified `execfile`, and so `deepcopy` is in scope even though it's not being preparsed because it's a `.py` file), but not when I import it (because said Python module doesn't magically get access to Sage names, and requires `from sage.all import *`).  Could you cut everything out from your `jbom.py` file except that needed to reproduce the problem and paste that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's what's going on:

You can only `import` files ending with `.py` (ignoring `.py[co]`)  These are standard Python files and aren't preparsed, so `1/3 == int(0)`, not `QQ(1)/QQ(3)`, and you don't have the equivalent of a `from sage.all import *` to play with.

You can `load` and `attach` both `.py` and `.sage` files (as well as `.pyx` and `.spyx` and `.m`).  Both have access to Sage definitions but the `.py` files aren't preparsed (so `y=17` makes `y` a Python `int`) while the `.sage` files are (so `y=17` makes `y` a Sage `Integer`).

So `import jbom` here works just like it would in Python, and you don't get the access to what Sage has put in scope.  `load` etc. are handy but they don't scale up to larger programs so well.  I've proposed improving this in the past and making `.sage` scripts less second-class citizens, but there hasn't yet been the mix of agreement on what to do and energy to do it.  In the meantime your best bet is to import from `sage.all`.

Comment: Thanks!  That might also explain some weird behavior I used to see about using division and the results turned out different from what I expected.